# Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData' after updating to Flutter 3.10

Tags: flutter, gradle, pubspec

I'm getting this error after updating to 3.10, and I don't reference accentColor in code. I assume it's one of the libraries that use this line. How do I check which one it is?

Error:

```
: Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
rectangle_indicator.dart:17
- 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
theme_data.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
    final borderColor = this.borderColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor;
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
triangle_indicator.dart:20
- 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
theme_data.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
          color: color ?? theme.accentColor,
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.1.6
  firebase_performance: ^0.9.0+16
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.17

  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  provider: ^6.0.4
  url_launcher: ^6.1.6
  flutter_boxicons: ^3.0.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^6.0.7096

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_fortune_wheel: ^1.2.0
  dynamic_color: ^1.6.3
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.6

  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
  purchases_flutter: ^4.11.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
  dependency_validator: ^3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `rectangle_indicator.dart:17` and `triangle_indicator.dart:20` which you can see comes from the `flutter_fortune_wheel` library.

Answer (score 0):

The `accentColor` is removed in the new version of flutter. 
You can use `colorScheme.secondayColor` instead of accentcolor.

Comment: The error is not being thrown in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` in the Android Studio terminal, and Do Invalidate caches and restart the IDE.